# "null is not an object (evaluating 'this.platform.injector')" when running Karma on an Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I have the immense pleasure of dealing with an Angular 4.4.7 application with no tests whatsoever. It uses Karma 1.7.0 under Node 8.16.2.

I would like to setup tests before I make any changes.

I am able to test a service, but I can't test a component using TestBed.

This is what I'm getting:

```
    Failed: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.platform.injector')
    _createCompilerAndModule@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-21168d2SqN4je6KOp.js:917:44
    compileComponents@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-21168d2SqN4je6KOp.js:867:55
    compileComponents@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-21168d2SqN4je6KOp.js:751:84
    src/components/login/login.component.spec.ts:8:24 <- src/components/login/login.component.spec.js:9:29
    invoke@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:31
    onInvoke@node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:45
    onInvoke@node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:47
    invoke@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:40
    runGuarded@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:53
    runInTestZone@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-21168d2SqN4je6KOp.js:235:35
    /tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-21168d2SqN4je6KOp.js:174:26
    invoke@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:31
    onInvoke@node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:45
    invoke@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:40
    run@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:141:49
    node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:102:37
    execute@node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:132:46
    execute@node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:132:46
    node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:129:134
    invokeTask@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:36
    runTask@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:57
    drainMicroTaskQueue@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:584:42
    invoke@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:490:44
```

```
// karma.conf.js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript'],
    files: [
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
      { pattern: 'node_modules/babel-polyfill/browser.js', instrument: false },
      { pattern: 'src/**/*.ts' },
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.ts': ['karma-typescript'], // Use karma-sourcemap-loader
    },
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-typescript'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
    ],
    angularCli: { environment: 'dev' },
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
    },
    reporters: ['mocha', 'progress', 'karma-typescript'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    karmaTypescriptConfig: {
      tsconfig: './src/tsconfig.spec.json',
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: 'coverage',
      },
    },
  });
};
```

```
// login.component.spec.ts
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('creates the component', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I cannot figure out why am I getting this error. Upgrading is not an option right now because there are no tests at all. How can I get this error to go away and test Angular components with this setup?

Comment: Can you please check your test.ts file, this issue was mentioned on github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16215

Comment: Thank you, I had seen this but was putting it in the wrong file. I guess I was too tired and frustrated yesterday. That fixed it, I put it in `src/test.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to `src/test.ts` fixed this error:

```
import {getTestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
```